# PHP/Ajax/jquery/JSON - Take a part from echo text back as a variable after Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on a simple Ajax post method and here is my code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


      $(window).scroll(function() {
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

                var nextUrl = "<?PHP echo $nexturl;?>";
                $('#Loading').show();
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'ajax.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: {
                    next_url: nextUrl
                  },
                }).done(function ( html ) {
                  $('#LoadedResults').html( html );
                  $('#Loading').hide();
                });



             }
    });
    });
  </script>
```

This code is sending post data to ajax.php:

```
<?PHP
 function callInstagram($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }


    $client_id = "1e0f576fbdb44e299924a93cace24507";
    $Next_URL = $_POST["next_url"];
    $url =  $Next_URL;

    $inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
    $results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);
    $maxid = $results['pagination']['next_max_id'];
    $nexturl = $results['pagination']['next_url'];
    //Now parse through the $results array to display your results... 


     echo json_encode(array(
        'next_url_link' => $nexturl
      ));
```

The ajax.php is echoing result as:

```
{"next_url_link":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/tags\/sweden\/media\/recent?count=24&client_id=1e0f576fbdb44e299924a93cace24507&max_tag_id=1427904820688670"}
```

I was looking here and there and i think there is some method with json with which i can get the result of `next_url_link`.

So guys, how can i get back the result printed for `next_url_link` and set is active jQuery/JavaScript variable ?

For example:

```
 var NextUrlLink = data.next_url_link;
```

Is it possible somehome ?
Should i create two .ajax post methods or how, i have no idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `JSON.parse()` for it.
So here is how you will do it :

```
.done(function ( html ) {
                  var data = JSON.parse(html);
                  //now use data.next_url_link
                  $('#LoadedResults').html(data.next_url_link);
                  $('#Loading').hide();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the success function to retrieve the data you encoded in your json

```
var NextUrlLink = []; //declare it as a global variable or somewhere within the same level or scope of where you want to use it so that you can use it

$.ajax({
                  url: 'ajax.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                    next_url: nextUrl
                  },
                  success:function(data){
                     NextUrlLink = data.next_url_link;
                  }

                })
```